# Remove marker line in Visual Studio 2012 (style)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, styling

I have a simple (*I think!*) styling question for Visual Studio 2012. As you can see **there's a marker around which line I have selected and am typing in** - **I would like to remove it**. But I cannot find how, any hints?

[image: The marker]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to remove it. Go into **`TOOLS->Options...`** then go to **`Text Editor->General`** and deselect **`"Highlight current line"`**. See image below.

[image: Remove selection indicator]